# how to set option COMPRESS in /etc/initramfs-tools

Tags: boot, partitioning, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu to the latest version, and I get this Error:

```
Not enough free disk space

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 430 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 37.8 M of disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt autoremove' and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your initramfs.
```

From gparted I read that my `/boot` partition is 732 MB, with 425 free. I would have gladly allocated more space to `/boot` to avoid this issue, but given where I'm at now, here's what I did:

- I ran `sudo apt autoremove` --this made no difference.
- I'm trying to add compression, but the instructions just say `set COMPRESS=xz ...`. Presumably, that means changing the following line in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` from this:

`COMPRESS=lz4`

to this:

`COMPRESS=gz`

... *but then what?* Should I save that file and then reboot? Should I log out and log back in again? Should I reinitialize something somewhere with some kind of command? More clarification here would be really helpful. What does it mean to "set" the `COMPRESS` value and what do I need to do after editing the above file for the changes to take effect?

Comment: you probably will need to regenerate the initramfs https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351911/what-does-regenerate-your-initramfs-mean

Comment: Possibly some files never got deleted that should have been; 732MB should be quite enough. can you post output of `sudo du -sh /boot/*` and `uname -a`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Type in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
```

It will open the file in the editor. 
Change `COMPRESS=zstd` to `COMPRESS=xz`

[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdaBG.png)

Then rebuild the images using

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: > " Then rebuild the images using sudo update-initramfs -u -k all"
<-- That was the crucial missing piece of info. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Also .. try changing

MODULES=most
to
MODULES=dep

in  /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
followed by

sudo update-initramfs -u -k all