# Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, no space in /boot. How to enlarge the partition?

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

When upgrading via `sudo do-release-upgrade`, the installer said to have not enough space and suggested the `sudo apt autoremove`. (I am not sure, but it was probably about the `/`.) So, I did it:

Also, the administrator of the virtual image increased the size, and then `growpart` was used to use the space:

[image: The growpart]

After the `growpart`:

[image: After growpart]

I have repeated the `sudo apt autoremove` (just to be sure). When trying the `do-release-upgrade` again, I can observe:

[image: The do-release-upgrade after adding space]

I believe (based only on what I remember) that this time is reported the `/boot` instead of `/`. The suggested `autoremove` have not released more space.

The `df -h` shows:

[image: The df -h]

So, probably the `/dev/sda1` size has to be increased. Is that correct?

Then... How can I increase the size of the `/dev/sha1`?

**Update after the first comments:** As possible alternative, I have another space allocated by the admin, and I could `growpart` the partion for the boot. Is there any way to move the other partitions to the end of the allocated disk to make space for extending the `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: Maybe you can create a bigger /boot partition in another location? With current /boot you can try: Use [linux-purge](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge) to delete more kernels. Also you could set `gz` compression for initramfs to save some space in /boot (though it is slower): [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426335/how-to-set-option-compress-in-etc-initramfs-tools)

Comment: @jarno: I need just about 7 MB to purge. However, I am not good in deciding what should be removed and what not. What `linux-purge` options you recommend to use? The snapshot of the virtual machine was done; so, I can return back if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Supposing your booted kernel works fine, you could purge all other kernels. So `sudo linux-purge --keep=0 --clear-boot` will save space. You could try with `--simulate` first to check what it is about to do. With `--choose` you get most control via interactive selection of kernels to remove.

Comment: Thanks, @jarno. Please, write that as the comment, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current /boot you can try: Use [linux-purge](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge) to delete more kernels. Supposing your booted kernel works fine you could purge all other kernels: `sudo linux-purge --keep=0 --clear-boot` will save space. You could try with `--simulate` first to check what it is about to do (though it will ask you for confirmation without it before purging unless you use `--yes`). With `--choose` you get most control via interactive selection of kernels to remove.

Besides you could set gz compression for initramfs to save some space in /boot (though it is slower): [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426335/how-to-set-option-compress-in-etc-initramfs-tools)