# How to change display pixel format from YCbCr 4:4:4 to Full RGB 4:4:4

Tags: display, amd-graphics, monitor, colors, amdgpu

**My monitor is displaying everything in pink-green color**

> I had same issue in Windows but fixed it by changing display's pixel format from **YCbCr 4:4:4** to **Full RGB 4:4:4** in **AMD Radeon software**. But how do I do that in Ubuntu?

[View image of my monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsVro.jpg)

I have **Ryzen 5 5600G no dGPU + Samsung monitor**

Answer (score 2):

The `amdgpu` drivers do not support switching the display pixel format. People are/were working on a fix for that feature, but none has been completed yet because of various issues. See [this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/476) for details.

However, there is a [hack](https://www.wezm.net/v2/posts/2020/linux-amdgpu-pixel-format/) involving changing the EDID data of the display, so that it only reports as supporting RGB and not YCbCr. It works as follows:

1. Install `wxedid` (must enable the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) first) using

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install wxedid
```

2. Find where the EDID for your monitor is stored using `xrandr --props`, then find where the EDID is listed for your monitor. If you are using Wayland, you may have to [switch to xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04) first in order for this to work.
3. get the EDID data from your monitor and copy it to a file on your device

```
cp /substitute/this/with/whatever/you/found/from/the/last/step  ~/edid.bin
```

4. run `wxedid` and edit the `edid.bin` file in your home directory. Do the following:

   1. Find SPF: Supported features -> vsig_format -> replace 0b01 wih 0b00
   2. Find CHD: CEA-861 header -> change the value of YCbCr420 and YCbCr444 to 0
   3. Recalculate the checksum: Options > Recalc Checksum
   4. Save the file
5. Tell the kernel to use the file:

   1. `sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/edid`
   2. `sudo mv edid.bin /lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin`
   3. [edit Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) to add the following kernel parameter: `drm.edid_firmware=HDMI-A-1:edid/edid.bin`
   4. [regenerate your initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351911/what-does-regenerate-your-initramfs-mean)
   5. reboot

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use these instructions but had a devil of a time with dumping edid.bin.  A mix of printf and perl finally seemed to work converting from ascii to hex:

```
printf '%b' $(xrandr --props | perl -pe 's/^((?![[:xdigit:]]{32}).)*$//g ; s/[\s\t]+//g ; s/([[:xdigit:]]{2})/\\x\1/g') > edid.bin
```

Use the expressions alone to check output:

```
 xrandr --props | perl -pe 's/^((?![[:xdigit:]]{32}).)*$//g ; s/[\s\t]+//g'
 xrandr --props | perl -pe 's/^((?![[:xdigit:]]{32}).)*$//g ; s/[\s\t]+//g ; s/([[:xdigit:]]{2})/\\x\1/g'
```

perl captures only lines that contain 32 hex characters, strips out whitespace/tabs, then reformats each two-digit pair to \x## so that printf interprets the escape sequence to ouput hex.  The other accepted [method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114359/how-to-get-edid-for-a-single-monitor/470122#470122) uses edid-decode:

```
 xrandr --verbose | edid-decode - edid.bin
```

It wouldn't work in a multi-monitor environment since multiple edids would be present.